# Eigenvalue by inspection?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can I guess the eigenvalues of a $3\times3$ matrix having all entries $1$?
for e.g., consider the matrix

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Since the rank of the matrix is $2$, it follows that $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$. The other eigenvalue follows easily from the trace. An alternative to finding the other eigenvalue is to note that the sum of the rows is constantly $3$, this implies that $\left(1,\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is an eigenpair of the matrix. It's also not hard to find two linearly independent eigenvectors of $0$ just by looking.

Comment: Since you're new at MSE, please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @GitGud I think you meant that the dimension of the kernel is 2 (the rank is 1). And the eigenvalue of the eigenpair you wrote should be 3, not 1.

Comment: @user156754 You're right on all accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You see that the kernel is two-dimensional, so you have that 0 is an eigenvalue with multiplicity two. Moreover if you act on the vector $(1,1,1)^t$ you obtain $(3,3,3)^t$, so 3 is the other eigenvalue.

Comment: How do you compute Kernel?

Comment: It is 3 minus the rank of the matrix: the rank is the number of linearly independent columns (or rows). In this case you have only one linearly independent column.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has eigenvalues $3$ and $0$.

One eigenvector is $x=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ - it is actually the transpose of one of the rows of the matrix. The associated eigenvalue is $3$.

Any vector $\ne 0$ orthogonal to $x$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: How do u compute? from trace ?